# Should I use metaclasses here?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, metaclass

I'm reading some data, which I want to create classes out of - this is done at load-time. The classes are grouped into a `Special` class, which can only be instantiated using run-time information. The classes depend on this `Special` class, so they can only be useful once it is created. Here is some simplified code that shows how I want it to work, using `random` instead of actual run-time info:

```
import random
def make_foo(param1, param2):
    class Foo:
        def __init__(self, special):
            self.param1 = param1
            self.param2 = param2
            self.special = special
        def do(self):
            print "%s is doing" % self
        def __str__(self):
            return "Foo<%s,%s with %s>" % (self.param1, self.param2,
                                           self.special)

    return Foo
def make_bar(foo):
    class Bar:
        def __init__(self, special):
            self.foo = foo(special)
        def do(self):
            print "%s is doing" % (self,)
        def __str__(self):
            return "Bar<%s>" % self.foo
    return Bar

def make_grouper(foobars):
    class Grouper:
        def __init__(self, special):
            self.foobars = [foobar(special) for foobar in foobars]
    return Grouper

def make_special(howtomake, groups):
    class Special:
        def __init__(self):
            self.important = random.choice(howtomake)
            self.groups = [group(self) for group in groups]
        def __str__(self):
            return "Special<%s>" % self.important
    return Special

Foo10_20 = make_foo(10, 20)
Foo30_40 = make_foo(30, 40)
Bar = make_bar(Foo10_20)
Grouper1 = make_grouper([Foo10_20, Foo30_40])
Grouper2 = make_grouper([Bar, Bar])

Special = make_special("IMPORTANTINFO", [Grouper1, Grouper2])

s = Special()
s.groups[0].foobars[0].do()
s.groups[0].foobars[1].do()
s.groups[1].foobars[0].do()

s = Special()
s.groups[0].foobars[0].do()
s.groups[0].foobars[1].do()
s.groups[1].foobars[0].do()
```

Sample output:

```
Foo<10,20 with Special<O>> is doing
Foo<30,40 with Special<O>> is doing
Bar<Foo<10,20 with Special<O>>> is doing
Foo<10,20 with Special<I>> is doing
Foo<30,40 with Special<I>> is doing
Bar<Foo<10,20 with Special<I>>> is doing
```

It can be summarized as having to create a set of classes which need to be bound to a `special` argument (so all the constructors, once the classes are done, just take a `special` argument). Can this be done more elegantly using meta-classes, or is this code fine the way it is?

Answer (score 3):

Since I generally prefer classes of closures in Python, I'd use factory classes here and avoid the use of dynamically created classes alltogether.  Example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, special):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.special = special
    def do(self):
        print "%s is doing" % self
    def __str__(self):
        return "Foo<%s,%s with %s>" % (self.param1, self.param2,
                                       self.special)

class FooFactory:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
    def __call__(self, special):
        return Foo(self.param1, self.param2, special)

foo_factory = FooFactory(1, 2)
foo = foo_factory(3)
```

An alternative to `FooFactory` would be the use of `functools.partial()`.  If `Foo` is defined as above, you could do

```
FooSpecialised = functools.partial(Foo, param1, param2)
```

and create instances of `Foo` by using

```
FooSpecialised(special)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not strictly an answer (or maybe it is) but I think this quote (MarkLutz, learning python 4 ed) of a quote from Tim Peters could be interesting:

> To borrow a quote from the
>   comp.lang.python newsgroup by veteran
>   Python core developer Tim Peters (who
>   is also the author of the famous
>   “import this” Python motto):
>
> [Metaclasses] are deeper magic than
>   99% of users should ever worry about.
>   If you wonder whether you need them,
>   you don’t (the people who actually
>   need them know with certainty that
>   they need them, and don’t need an
>   explanation about why).

Comment: aye i read that but brushed it off, but thanks for bringing it up. i felt i needed something.. if anything the concept of what i was doing was off. but the factory idea worked well and i'm using that

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a base class:

```
class Base(object):
    @classmethod
    def bind_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        def init(special):
            return cls(special, *args, **kwargs)
        return init
```

Foo et. al. are a normal-looking non-dynamic classes now:

```
class Foo(Base):
    def __init__(self, special, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.special = special
    def do(self):
        print "%s is doing" % self
    def __str__(self):
        return "Foo<%s,%s with %s>" % (self.param1, self.param2,
                                       self.special)
```

and they are used as follows:

```
Foo10_20 = Foo.bind_init(10, 20)
Foo30_40 = Foo.bind_init(30, 40)
Bar = Bar.bind_init(Foo10_20)
Grouper1 = Grouper.bind_init([Foo10_20, Foo30_40])
Grouper2 = Grouper.bind_init([Bar, Bar])

Special = Special.bind_init("IMPORTANTINFO", [Grouper1, Grouper2])
```

this minimizes code repetition (don't have to make tons of factory classes) and I also like the lingo much more than class factory.